# Maven - Failed to resolve artifact - cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:null

Tags: maven, cglib

I'm trying to build a large project and failing with the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Utilities
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1255 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 16 resources
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Couldn't find a version in [2.2.2] to match range [2.1_3,2.1_3]
  cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:null

from the specified remote repositories:
  java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2),
  internal (http://repo.some-project.org/maven),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Path to dependency:
        1) org.some-project:util:jar:1.5.0
```

I [found](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cglib/files/cglib2/cglib%202.1_03/) and downloaded `cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar`
As I lack experience with maven, I'm not sure how to (hrr...) make the build process use this file instead of failing on (I guess) fetching it from the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cglib version 2.1_3 has been removed from the main maven repo in favor of 2.2.2
Try updating your dependency to 2.2.2 - who knows, perhaps it'll work :)
If it doesn't, download 2.1_3 (from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/) for example) and [manually install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) it locally.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm able to find it: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=cglib/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar Anyway, if 2.2.2 works for you, that's great :)

Comment: @Tarlog - For me out of all the hundreds of dependencies in the project, it consistently didn't find only this one

Comment: @Tarlog - 2.2.2 didn't work for me, I had to manually install 2.1_3 locally :)

Answer (score 6):

It is working if you put in the `dependencyManagement` section, instead of putting it in the `dependencies` section.

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>     
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>     
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>     
        <version>2.1_2</version> 
      </dependency>     
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

All the versions are working. I was getting the same error when I had put it in the   `dependencies` section instead of `dependencyManagement` section. You need not do it 
 manually.

Answer (score 2):

In your pom.xml under the `dependencyManagement` section add:

```
<project>
 ...
 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
  ...
   <dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>2.1_3</version>
    </dependency>
  ....
```

Comment: If you don't have it, just add it :) It should be somewhere under the project element.

Comment: I added it - same error. for some reason (I think) it's finding only 2.2.2 online while I require 2.1_3